# Omniauth mock up not working in rails rspec. Google Login button not getting clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, omniauth

After following tutorials from internet of integration test of Google Login in Rails. I came to this. But it's not working.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

def stub_omniauth
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
        provider: "google_oauth2",
        uid: "12345678910",
        info: {
            email: "limsammy1@gmail.com",
            first_name: "Sam",
            last_name: "Lim"
        },
        credentials: {
            token: "abcdefg12345",
            refresh_token: "abcdefg12345",
            expires_at: DateTime.now,
        }
    })
end

RSpec.feature "user logs in" do
    scenario "using google oauth2" do
        visit login_path
        stub_omniauth
        Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:google_oauth2]
        expect(page).to have_css("a.google-login-button")
        find("a.google-login-button").click
        expect(page.current_path).to eq(dashboard_path)
    end
end
```

I am supposing that after running the test my page content would change but they are same as before.